# Proper sitemap.xml setup

Tags: seo, xml-sitemap

I have a dynamic site which has many (well, less than 50) users.  Each user is allowed to create as many pages as they want.  I know that there is a limit to how many pages you can be listed in sitemap.xml, and for now I am under that limit, but I would like to know what the best way to enable search engines to know (all?) about my user's pages while still being under that limit even if I have more than the limit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Sitemap Limits:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps#Sitemap_limits)

> Sitemap files have a limit of 50,000
>   URLs and 10 megabytes per sitemap.
>   Sitemaps can be compressed using gzip,
>   reducing bandwidth consumption.
>   Multiple sitemap files are supported,
>   with a Sitemap index file serving as
>   an entry point for a total of 1000
>   Sitemaps.

Note that you can specify [multiple sitemaps in your robots.txt file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt#Sitemap):

If you're bumping into the limitation, perhaps divide your users up somehow. Let's say each of your users has no more than 10,000 urls a piece, you could break it up into files and add this to your `robots.txt` file:

```
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemaps/users-001-005.xml
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemaps/users-006-010.xml
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemaps/users-011-015.xml
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemaps/users-016-020.xml
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemaps/users-021-025.xml
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemaps/users-026-030.xml
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemaps/users-031-035.xml
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemaps/users-036-040.xml
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemaps/users-041-045.xml
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemaps/users-046-050.xml
```

Now, you'd still have to be mindful of the 10MB limit for each individual sitemap, but this is an approach to handle the "too many" urls problem.

See the [CNN](http://www.cnn.com/robots.txt) and [Google](http://www.google.com/robots.txt) `robots.txt` files to see multiple sitemaps in action.

Comment: Note: the 10 MB limit is per sitemap, not total

Comment: It may be worth linking to and giving an example of the Sitemap Index file:  http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php#index  This is used by many sites as well, and has the benefits of drill-down in google webmaster tools.  Couple examples: http://www.nanaimo.ca/sitemap.xml  http://www.barnonedrinks.com/sitemap.xml

Comment: Has anyone actually _seen_ a 10MB sitemap? Yeowzerz!

Comment: I haven't seen a 10 MB sitemap, but here's one with 50,000 urls: http://www.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sitemaps/sitemap_co_kr_ko_0002.xml.gz

Comment: (found in a few minutes by browsing some sitemaps for cnn and google and a few other large news/archive sites)